# Facebook oAuth user details with MVC 4

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, twitter-oauth, facebook-oauth

I am using the `OAuthWebSecurity` with `MVC` to allow users of my website to login using Facebook's oAuth.  Everything works fine, and I have a test user authenticating fine.

My question is based on the details Facebook can provide.  I am currently returning the user details using the following...

```
AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication();
```

This will give the follwing details:

- UserName (email)
- ProviderUserId

I also get a `ExternalData` object which has:

- UserName
- Name
- Gender

Do you know if it's possible to get further data, maybe DoB, photo etc?

Comment: Have you read the docs and all? You can fetch n number of things- each associated with a permission. Start here: http://developers.facebook.com

Comment: The documentation specifies how to get the additional data? Where in the document will I find this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can start from here: http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/tutorial/

Comment: This is the reason I've posted the question, if it can't be achieved, I don't want to read all the documentation to find it can't be achieved.

Comment: Well, these are the basic things; you'll find them at the start of the documentation. Good luck! :)

Comment: Yes you can fetch as much as u want...if user approves your app permissions. In the app ,you have to specify your permissions,suppose DOB, so when user logs into your app, he will be asked to approve this permission. Once he approves it, you can fetch the DOB. Hope this helps.

Comment: @aviral, OK, so where would I specify this?

Comment: It is specified in the app settings. Explore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon me for not framing me the full answer. I am just supplying a link. Please check

http://blue-and-orange.net/articles/facebook/displaying-facebook-user-data-in-aspnet-mvc-4/

Everything is explained here.

For setting permission you can go through this documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/

if you were to request a user's email address, but never asked them for the 'email' permission, you would receive an OAuth error as show below.

```
try {
var client = new FacebookClient("my_access_token");
dynamic result = client.Get("me/email");
var email = (string)result.email;
```

}

```
catch (FacebookOAuthException) {
    // The access token expired or the user 
    // has not granted your app 'email' permission.
    // Handle this by redirecting the user to the
    // Facebook authenticate and ask for email permission.
}
```